# Junit: How to check if 2 collections are equals with elements in different order?

Tags: java, junit, collections, assertion

I am trying to check if two collections are the same using Assertions. They are supposed to be the same, even if their elements are in different order.

Here is my method for checking equality:

```
 public static <T> void assertCollectionsAreEquals (Collection<T> expected, Collection<T> actual, String message) {
        Assertions.assertEquals(expected, actual, message);    
        }
```

Example collections:

```
        Collection <Integer> one = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Collection <Integer> two = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Collection <Integer> three = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        one.add(1);
        one.add(2);
        two.add(1);
        two.add(2);
        three.add(2);
        three.add(1);
```

So my collections look like this:

```
One:[1, 2]
Two:[1, 2]
Three:[2, 1]
```

Test:

```
assertCollectionsAreEquals(one, two, "Not Equals");
assertCollectionsAreEquals(one, three, "Not Equals");
```

Output:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: Not Equals ==> expected: <[1, 2]> but was: <[2, 1]>
```

How do I make my tests succeed for all of my test collections?

Comment: Sort the collections first then compare them.

Comment: "They should be the same, even if the order is different", so, what's the adversion to `Set`?

Comment: The notion of `equals()` is not defined at that level in the hierarchy, and a usable definition depends wholly on the specific collection's contract.  Your method accepts any `Collection` but you couldn't apply it to a `List<>` and a `Set<>`. Before you can answer the question you need to consider the actual implementations and their behaviors.

Comment: You might want to consider a different assertion library that has a richer set of assertions than those built in to junit. For example in assertJ you could use `assertThat(one).containsExactlyInAnyOrder(two)`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To check equality of two collections, the size of the two collections should be compared, next a difference may be calculated by removing elements in collection `c2` from the copy of collection `c1` and if it's empty the collections are equal:

```java
public static <T> boolean areCollectionsEqual(Collection<T> c1, Collection<T> c2) {
    if (c1 == c2) return true;
    
    if (c1 == null || c2 == null || c1.size() != c2.size()) {
        return false;
    }
    
    Collection<T> tmp = new ArrayList<>(c1);
    for (T item : c2) {
        if (!tmp.remove(item)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    
    return tmp.isEmpty();
}
```

Such method allows to compare different types of collections (e.g. `List` to `Set`)

Then common `assertTrue` / `assertFalse` may be used in tests:

```java
public static <T> void assertCollectionsAreEqual(Collection<T> expected, Collection<T> actual, String message) {
    Assertions.assertTrue(areCollectionsEqual(expected, actual), message);    
}

public static <T> void assertCollectionsAreNotEqual(Collection<T> expected, Collection<T> actual, String message) {
    Assertions.assertFalse(areCollectionsEqual(expected, actual), message);    
}
```

---

*Update* `Collection::removeAll` may produce incorrect result in the case when the collections contain the same elements with different frequencies. e.g. `List.of (1, 2, 2, 2)` and `List.of (1, 2, 1, 2)`, so it was replaced with iterative `remove`.

Comment: Two problems: First, the question is under-specified and must consider what it means to compare different types of collections for equality.  Second, your solution can produce incorrect results.   Consider an _expected_ `List{1,2,3}` and an _actual_ `List{1,2,3,4}`.  `removeAll(Collection c)` removes every element `e` of `this` where `c.contains(e)` returns `true`.  So even though the the lists are most definitely NOT equal, after `expected.removeAll(actual)`, the result is empty and you would return `true`.

Comment: The main issue is that `a.removeAll(b)` and `b.removeAll(a)` must BOTH be tested and the collections are equal only if both result in empty lists.

Comment: `{1, 2, 3}` and `{1, 2, 3, 4}` are not equal by size; however, `removeAll` does not seem to be fit for this task and I have replaced it with iterative `remove`.

Answer (score 0):

There's no ready-made assertion method in JUnit 5 to accomplish this. You could use Hamcrest instead:

```
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.containsInAnyOrder;

assertThat("Not Equals", one, containsInAnyOrder(two.toArray()));
assertThat("Not Equals", one, containsInAnyOrder(three.toArray()));
```

Answer (score 0):

To test if `one` and `two` are equal:

First check that the two collections have the same size:

```
assertEquals(one.size(), two.size());
```

Then make sure that they contain the same elements:

```
assertTrue(one.containsAll(two));
assertTrue(two.containsAll(one));
```

If these two conditions are met, `one` and `two` should contain the same elements (given that the order doesn't matter here).

E.g. let

```
Set<Integer> one = Set.of(1, 2, 3);
Set<Integer> two = Set.of(2, 1, 4);
```

The condition of equality passes, but

```
assertTrue(one.containsAll(two));
```

will fail.

Comment: Can you please add some explanations to your code?